# (SFML Visual Studio 2017 C++) (SPP:TPR) main.cpp cannot find dependent dll despite correct installation - could indicate deeper-rooted issue(s)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, sfml

**Hello.**

I've just recently started my (definitive) C++ version of a Mario 80's-arcade-style-faithful fangame I've been working on for at least 2 years now: Super Princess Peach: The Prince Rescue (which was the abbreviation from the title mentioned in the beginning), now as an engine instead of a standalone game as before. it was originally started in the Construct 3 engine, but I've figured I'd design the entire game itself from scratch and in pure raw form to have the most power and flexibility possible, especially considering I should start actually working with pure, raw language code (C++) at some point in my life as a general media developer.

However, as I was performing the first test on the engine itself, I've noticed a particularly concerning error stating it could not find a .dll file despite it actually already being in the fresh SFML installation itself. What's "particularly concerning" about this error is the fact that this specific .dll it could not find was actually already on the installation itself - and on a fresh one at that.

In other words, according to the title, this may indicate much more serious, deeper-rooted issues with the entire process of trying to test the engine as a whole than I originally anticipated. Stuff like this does **not** seem like normal problems; the kind that might have just required some tweaking on my own end by myself or just required a simple answer/fix otherwise.

Also worth noting is that this issue had occurred within less than 3 months of having received my new computer (which is technically so because my dad originally bought me this computer but then sent it back immediately because I was interested in a 2-in-1 convertible laptop instead for multipurpose purposes), and within less than a month of actual usage. Also, it's important to note that due to serious problems with the first Windows 10 installation as a whole on it, in around less than 2 weeks, I had reset my entire PC (that early on), and therefore I'm actually on my second installation of Windows 10 on this PC.

What's exactly going on is that the program seemingly cannot find the .dll file *sfml-system-2.dll* at all, but the problem with that is that it's actually *already* on the SFML installation itself - and on a *fresh* one at that. All the files, including the "missing" dictionary, are all in their proper places, and everything, from file paths and Dependencies, to Configuration, Platform, and Target Machine setups have all been set up correctly when this error occurred - and it still does even then.

I've actually attempted several fixes in order to resolve the issue feeling like there may have just been bad connections or the like, including reinstallations of Visual Studio and SFML, and relinking the required SFML file paths and Dependencies, using different Configurations and Platforms, including "all" to make sure all possible bases are covered, and linking the files differently in the hope of bypassing certain restrictions or roadblocks which may have just all that had been present. Unfortunately, none of these methods worked, and I have not made any progress on the problem so far.

This is why I'm posting this question right now. I may have a much more serious issue on my hands than what I've originally presumed.

---

**Here's the actual error message in text form itself:**

`The code execution cannot proceed because sfml-system-2.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.`

**And now, here are two images depicting the entire problem in visual format.**

---

The actual error message upon execution

[image: The actual error message upon execution]

The actual /bin folder itself for my installation of SFML. The red box is where the files are, and the green box shows that the sfml-system-2.dll is in fact actually there.

[image: The actual /bin folder itself for my installation of SFML. The red box is where the files are, and the green box shows that the sfml-system-2.dll is in fact actually there.]

---

To end this, normally, this would be the sort of problem that I would probably expect to just get a simple answer/fix for. But given everything in the test program itself is set up perfectly correctly and yet this error still somehow occurs, this problem looks to be a lot more concerning especially to me than one or I might have originally anticipated.

---

**By the way, here's the full code for the entire test program/project itself, just in case this entire issue as a whole may have something to do with my code somehow.**

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Include Required Libraries.
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
// Main Code.
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "All Systems Go");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close(); } }
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display(); }
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
    return 0; }
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

---

Thank you so much in advance. Your help absolutely means a lot to me.

Comment: Is `sfml-system-2.dll` in the same folder as your applications executable or in one of the folders of your `PATH` environment variable? If either of these are the case are you sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit? Also you should be careful not to mix debug and release. There likley should be different dlls for debug than release and these should not be mixed.

Comment: I don't seem to have the executable in the program itself at all. Also, I can't really tell the difference between 32 and 64 bit with Visual Studio since the install never mentioned the version it was, and debug and release. I'm only relatively new to computer programming and coding, as you might realize.

Comment: You can setup your windows PATH environment variable instead of copying your dlls to the same folder as the executable. [https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you need to place `sfml-system-2.dll` (along with the .dll files of any other SFML subsystems you use) inside the same directory as your executable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just figured one solution out. Putting the .dll files into the executable's folder had just solved the problem. The program is now working normally and correctly. Thank you. - By the way, the original reason I came here is because I followed every step in the official SFML installation tutorial about putting it into your program correctly, and I still got that error. I felt like it could be something much more serious, and so I came here. Turns out the tutorial literally made no mention that I was supposed to put the .dll files into the executable's folder. lol.